# Filter By does nor have search option in SP List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, search, list-view, modern-experience

In my column header drop down in list view, when I choose "Filter By" option, there is No search option, Only check boxes.

There are different column types and in neither of them I can type in to search.

What am I missing?

Comment: Which column type are you using?

Comment: Hi some are Lookup and some are date-time columns.

Comment: This is default behavior in SharePoint. Search in filter by is available for text and person/people columns but not for number, choice, date and lookup columns.

Comment: Okay thanks. And there is no way to change that? (Just to clarify)

Comment: Unfortunately, No. Check my answer below for details.

Comment: Please and [accept my below response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior in SharePoint Online modern experience list views.

As per my testing, text search option in "Filter by" pane is available for:

1. Single line of text and
2. Person or group (people) columns, etc.

And text search option in "Filter by" pane is not available for:

1. Number
2. Choice
3. Date and Time
4. Lookup columns, etc.

Also, there is no way to customize/change this behavior in SharePoint online modern experience as it is a SharePoint out of the box feature.